# Calculate amount of mugs StackExchange should give away so I'll receive one

Tags: beginner, sql, sql-server, stackexchange

#### Description

Calculate how many mugs StackExchange should give away(for graduation) to top reputed users on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so I'll also receive one. (output is divisible by 50).

#### Code

```
DECLARE @mugs INT,@rounded_mugs INT,@inc INT,@remainder INT;
SELECT  @mugs = COUNT(1) FROM Users WHERE Reputation >= 
  (SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE DisplayName='JaDogg');
SET  @remainder = @mugs%50;
IF (@remainder = 0) SET @inc = 0 ELSE SET @inc=50-@remainder; 
SELECT  @mugs+@inc AS 'AMOUNT OF MUGS TO GIVE AWAY';
```

### Link

[Calculate amount of mugs to give away so I'll receive one](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/238166/calculate-amount-of-mugs-to-give-away-so-ill-receive-one)

Comment: The query could take a `username` parameter ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug don't steal my review ;)

Comment: you can get the all-time rankings on SE *User Reputation Leagues*: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/86/alltime/codereview

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Documentation

I think that what the query is doing is looking at your reputation rank, then rounding up to the nearest 50.  It would be nice to hit "edit description" and document that for the benefit of anyone else using Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

### Generality

Data Explorer allows parameterization.  Use it.

### Style

You shouldn't have to declare variables for such a simple query.  In SQL, try to say what you want.  Don't state the steps for calculating it.

A good way to avoid defining variables is to use Common Table Expressions (the `WITH` clause) instead.

### Brevity

It would help to use the relevant functions [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) and [`CEILING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx).

```
WITH UserRanks AS (
    SELECT DisplayName
         , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS RepRank
        FROM Users
)
SELECT *, 50 * CEILING((RepRank + 0.0) / 50) AS BatchedRepRank
    FROM UserRanks
    WHERE DisplayName = ##Username:string##;
```

Comment: Since RepRank is an integer, you can also do `50*((RepRank + 49)/50)` to avoid type conversions.

Comment: Silly me. I only needed one CTE, not two. Corrected in Rev 2.

Answer (score 11):

Stylistically I'd declare variables just like in program code: Each on a single line.

Also your nested Select seems a little forced and cramped, as well as the calculation code. You maybe want to add a *little* whitespace there ;)

Well now now, I actually wouldn't want you to get a Mug, but I'd want one myself...
<sub>slightly jesting</sub>

How many mugs would have to be given away, for *me* to recieve one? Your query cannot answer that. As already pointed out by [Mat'sMug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) (*badum, tss*) in [a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67703/calculate-amount-of-mugs-stackexchange-should-give-away-so-ill-receive-one/67705#comment123456_67703), you could use a username parameter.

I would have written this somewhat like:

```
DECLARE @mugs INT;
DECLARE @rounded_mugs INT;
DECLARE @inc INT;
DECLARE @remainder INT;

SELECT  @mugs = COUNT(1) 
FROM Users 
WHERE Reputation >= (SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE DisplayName=##username:string?Community##);

SET  @remainder = @mugs%50;
IF (@remainder = 0) 
  SET @inc = 0 
ELSE 
  SET @inc=50-@remainder; 

SELECT  @mugs+@inc AS 'Amount of mugs to give away';
```